# Measure of the set of numbers in $[0,1]$ expressed with different quantities of zeroes and ones in binary

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, binary, law-of-large-numbers

I read a Math Overflow [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/q/43511) recently that claimed the set of numbers in $[0,1]$ whose binary expansion contained a different number of 0 and 1 digits (i.e. doesn't include numbers like $0.\overline{10}_2$) has zero Lebesgue measure, which the user said is implied by the Strong Law of Large Numbers. This is probably my inexperience talking, but I can't even see the connection between those two concepts, much less how one implies the other is true.

It also seems strange to me that this set and not its complement in $[0,1]$ would have zero measure, since there are $\frac {n!}{(\frac n2!)^2}$ binary numbers expressed with half zeroes and ones up to the nth digit after the radix point, which is less than the amount of numbers that do not satisfy this (that being $2^n-\frac {n!}{(\frac n2!)^2}$) for every $n\in2\Bbb N, n\gt2$. Though, admittedly, this logic may not apply to uncountable sets.

Could anyone explain or prove that either this set or its complement in $[0,1]$ has zero measure?

Comment: I don't understand the condition.  For an infinite string, what does it mean to say that it has more $1's$ than $0's$?  I expect that if you define that carefully, the answer to your question will follow.

Comment: Please link to the question you reference; perhaps the relevant definition is included there.

Comment: You say $0.\overline{10}_2$ has the same number of $0$s and $1$s.  What about $0.00\overline{10}_2$ or $0.\overline{110}_2$? They also have an infinite number of each.

Comment: I think we're talking about binary expansions where the ratio of ones to zeros doesn't approach one in the limit as you go farther out in the expansion. That is a set of measure zero, and this has probably been demonstrated on this website many times.

Comment: The condition means to say that the number of 1s in the first n binary places does not converge to n/2 as n increases. The answer I'm referring to is the one by Andreas Blass on this question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43478/is-there-a-measure-zero-set-which-isnt-meagre

Comment: In fact something even stronger is true, which is that the set of [non-normal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number) has measure $0$. One way to think about it is like this: let's ask a different question: if I flip a coin infinitely many times, and $h_n$ is the number of heads in the first $n$ flips, what is the probability that $\lim_{n \to \infty} h_n/n = \tfrac 12$? By the SLLN, the answer is $1$. Indeed if you think of the binary expansion of $x \in [0, 1]$ as "coin flips", this actually proves your result.

Comment: You're right that the number of $n$-digit binary strings with an exact 50-50 split between $0$s and $1$s is quite small. However that's not what we're interested in - we just need the split to *approach* 50-50. EG for very large $n$, the number of binary strings with between $0.4999n$ and $0.5001n$ $0$s is huge, and many of these numbers "end up" having "the same" number of $0$s and $1$s. Indeed for large $n$, if $X_n$ is binomially distributed as $B(n, \tfrac 12)$, then $X_n/n$ has a tiny variance! This isn't quite a rigorous argument, but perhaps it can help with your intuition a bit.

Comment: "converge to $n/2$" doesn't make sense, since $n/2$ isn't a constant (and isn't even an integer, if $n$ is odd, so it's not even a possible value for the number of ones). Try to understand the way I phrased it in my comment.

Comment: Are you still here, Andrey?